# Extracting Arguments from a Function Passed as a Parameter to Another Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I am new to JavaScript. I have a small program where a function takes another function as a parameter. I am trying to extract/access the arguments of the function passed as a parameter. Here's an example:

```
function test(precondition, postcondition, func)   {
   // Extract arguments of func which in this case should be 5 and 6
   // This is required to check whether isNumber(5) and isNumber(6)
   // both return true, so that precondition is met
 }

var add = test((isNumber, isNumber), isNumber,
            function add(x, y) {return x+y; });

console.log(add (5, 6));
```

isNumber is a function that returns true if an input is a number (already defined).
Tried to provide a minimal and executable code as required by rules. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It's not possible as stated. `test` only sees the result after `add` has finished and its call has resolved to the number `11`. You'll have to detect it earlier in the chain, eg `add(test(5, 6))` but I don't know if that's what you're looking for

Comment: This is actually a simplified version of the programming contracts problem. My test() function takes in 3 parameters: precondition, post-condition (return type) and a function itself. I need the function's arguments to check whether preconditions are met i.e that both 5 and 6 are Numbers.

Comment: Please post the *actual code* then, not the simplified code

Comment: javascript closure can help

Comment: This would work `function add(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

function test(func, p1, p2) {
  console.log(arguments) <
    console.log(func(p1, p2));
}

var x = test(add, 5, 6);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that only requires you to change the code in `test` (with the exception of your call to test where I've replaced `(isNumber, isNumber)` with `[isNumber, isNumber]`).

You don't have to do anything special to get access to `add`'s arguments because you create the function inside `test` and return it to be called by `console.log(add(5, 6));`.

Using `arguments` inside any function will give you the function's arguments as an array.

The `...` in `func(... arguments);` is the spread operate which takes an array and expands it in place. See [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
function test(precondition, postcondition, func)   {
   // Extract arguments of func which in this case should be 5 and 6
   // This is required to check whether isNumber(5) and isNumber(6)
   // both return true, so that precondition is met  
  return function() {
    for (const i in arguments) {
      const argi = arguments[i];
      const precondition_i = precondition[i];
      console.log('precondition['+i+'] met: ' + precondition_i(argi));
    }
    const r = func(... arguments);
    console.log('postcondition met: ' + postcondition(r));
    return r;
  };
 }

var add = test([isNumber, isNumber], isNumber, function add(x, y) {return x+y; });

console.log(add(5, 6));
```

Or a less generic solution that doesn't use `arguments` and `...` and doesn't pass in an array as `precondition`:

```
function test(precondition, postcondition, func)   {
  // Extract arguments of func which in this case should be 5 and 6
  // This is required to check whether isNumber(5) and isNumber(6)
  // both return true, so that precondition is met  
  return function(x, y) {
    console.log('precondition met for x: ' + precondition(x));
    console.log('precondition met for y: ' + precondition(y));
    const r = func(x, y);
    console.log('postcondition met: ' + postcondition(r));
    return r;
  };
 }

var add = test(isNumber, isNumber, function add(x, y) {return x+y; });

console.log(add(5, 6));
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, and sorry for the delayed response. I might have more questions about this :)

Comment: Excellent, if you have any more questions about it just let me know.

Comment: Ok, so the method returns a function. If either a precondition or postcondition are not met, I simply want to print the error message (I know how to do it) and return. If I call the above method as add(5, "six") the result will print 5six which I do not need. Simply print an error message and return. I was able to create a workaround by returning "" if preconditions or a postcondition is violated. This just puts an empty line at the end. But I was wondering if there is a better way of handling this. Thank you!

Comment: I think just returning `""` if pre/post conditions are not met makes sense. The other option that comes to mind is to do `throw "Conditions not met.";` but then code after the call to `add(5, 'six')` won't be reached so that might not be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. So just to confirm, the reason you are able to call add(5, 6) is because variable add is the reference to the function returned by the function test? Since function test returns an anonymous function to the variable add we can invoke this returned function by using add(5, 6) (or other arguments). Is this correct?

Comment: I have one last question about it and then I'll stop. Suppose I have the following constructor and object created as: function Obj(first, last) {this.first = first; this.last = last; } Obj.prototype.method = test ([isNumber, isNumber], isNumber, function add(x, y) {return x + y });  (basically exactly as defined above). Then creating let a = new Obj("John", "Doe") and calling a.method() does not do anything since "this" in the constructor points to the global object.  How could I modify "test" function using "apply" (so that "this" points to the Obj) to make this work? Thank you.

Comment: If you change `const r = func(... arguments);` to `const r = func.apply(this, arguments);` then inside the `add` function `this` will refer to `a` (the instance of `Obj`). Not 100% sure I understood correctly. Is that what you were asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `test` inside `add` and pass only `add`'s parameters rather than the function call:

```
 function add(a,b){
     test(a,b)
     //and some code
 }
```

Comment: Yes, the original problem does very similar to this. My question is, inside test, how do I access arguments of add? How do I access 5 and 6?

Comment: @AlexanderNenartovich `test` is called in `add` function?

Comment: No, add() is a function passed as a parameter to test(). It is not important to check what add() evaluates to. All I need to do is check that both arguments of add() are numbers, and I need to do so inside the test() function. This is why I need access to the arguments of add(). Unless there is some workaround. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var test=function(d,c){
    this.a=d;
    this.b=c;
    this.add=function(){
        return this.a+this.b;
    }
}
var my_test=new test(5,6);
console.log(my_test.a);   // return 5
console.log(my_test.b);  // return 6
console.log(my_test.add());  //return 11
```